# need help with joining the 2 tables on closest date

Tags: mysql, join

I am a newbie in SQL and need help with the joining of these 2 tables on the closest date. Thanks in Advance!

Table A

| billing_start_date | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-07-27 | 100 | active |
| 2018-12-27 | 101 | inactive |

Table B

| period_end_date | id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-21 | 100 | 4 | 5 |
| 2018-12-28 | 100 | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-07-24 | 101 | 3 | 4 |
| 2020-07-31 | 101 | 2 | 3 |

Output

| period_end_date | id | period_end_date | status | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-27 | 100 | 2018-12-28 | active | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-07-27 | 101 | 2020-07-24 | inactive | 3 | 4 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, can you explain how you got your output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please go to dbfiddle.uk and create your tables and sample data and maybe include a bit more of an explanation of your requirements...

Comment: Also, please **always** include your server version with your questions!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this - it makes the assumption that `billing_start_date`, `id` and `status` will remain the same.

I've used MySQL 8 to do this - previous versions have problems with `GROUP BY` (Google `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to find out about this - it's become the default in version 8, so no risk of being tripped up by this particularly egregious bug).

All of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc340196e29b46ba10cb21658eb318db).

First, I started by creating the tables and records as per your data (this is really your job - it eliminates duplication of effort and provides a single source of truth):

```
CREATE TABLE billing_start  -- your table_a - I try to give my tables meaningful names!
(
  billing_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  id                 SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  status             VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
);
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO billing_start VALUES
('2020-07-27', 100, 'active'),
('2018-12-27', 101, 'inactive');
```

and the other table:

```
CREATE TABLE period_end
(
  period_end_date DATE NOT NULL,
  id              SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  code_a          TINYINT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  code_b          TINYINT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO period_end VALUES
('2018-12-21',  100,    4,  5),
('2018-12-28',  100,    2,  3),
('2020-07-24',  101,    3,  4),
('2020-07-31',  101,    2,  3);
```

Then, I pick out the date differences as follows:

```
SELECT 
  b.billing_start_date AS bsd, b.id AS bid, b.status,
  ABS(p.period_end_date - b.billing_start_date) AS diff
FROM billing_start b
JOIN period_end    p
  ON b.id = p.id;
```

Result:

```
bsd     bid     status  diff
2020-07-27  100     active  19506
2020-07-27  100     active  19499
2018-12-27  101     inactive    19497
2018-12-27  101     inactive    19504
```

Note the use of the [`ABS()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-abs-function.php) function... it's required to get the smallest gap in the dates!

Then I use the above result in a subquery to get the `billing_start` table records with a given `id` and `status` which match the criteria! But I hold onto the differences in date so I can `JOIN` back to the `period_end` table using these dates as the `JOIN`ing criterion.

```
SELECT bsd, bid, bstat, MIN(diff) AS mdiff
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    b.billing_start_date AS bsd, b.id AS bid, b.status AS bstat,
    ABS(p.period_end_date - b.billing_start_date) AS diff
  FROM billing_start b
  JOIN period_end    p
    ON b.id = p.id  
) AS tab1
GROUP BY bsd, bid, bstat;
```

Result:

```
bsd     bid     bstat   mdiff
2020-07-27  100     active  19499
2018-12-27  101     inactive    19497
```

Finally, I join back to the `period_end` table as explained above:

```
SELECT 
  t.bsd, t.bid, t.bstat, p.period_end_date, p.id, mdiff,
  p.period_end_date - t.bsd, p.code_a, p.code_b
FROM
(
  SELECT bsd, bid, bstat, MIN(diff) AS mdiff
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      b.billing_start_date AS bsd, b.id AS bid, b.status AS bstat,
      ABS(p.period_end_date - b.billing_start_date) AS diff
    FROM billing_start b
    JOIN period_end    p
      ON b.id = p.id  
  ) AS tab1
  GROUP BY bsd, bid, bstat
) AS t
JOIN period_end p
  ON  t.bid = p.id
  WHERE ABS(p.period_end_date - t.bsd) = ABS(mdiff)
ORDER BY t.bid;
```

Result:

```
bsd        bid  bstat   period_end_date id  mdiff   p.period_end_date - t.bsd   code_a  code_b
2020-07-27 100  active   2018-12-28     100  19499  -19499                   2  3
2018-12-27 101  inactive 2020-07-24     101  19497   19497                   3  4
```

Et voilà! The desired result!

I left the date differences in (and in the fiddle) to show my line of thinking. Tricky enough question - +1! But next time, please put in your server version and please go to the trouble of constructing a fiddle - help us to help you!